# Difference between magic table and temporal (system versioned) table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the difference between magic table and temporal (system versioned) table in SQL Server?

Comment: Define *magic* table ...... this is not a generally known / accepted term .....

Answer (score 0):

Magic Table

- Virtual and No Physical Existence. SQL Server internally maintain magic table.
- There are two table name INSERTED and DELETED.
- INSERTED contains information about newly inserted or updated record in table.
- DELETED contains information about last state of that table record.
- Now if you perform two update operation on two table then INSERTED and DELETED megic table updated accoridignly and atleast available in trigger.
- Apart from Trigger you can use with output clause.

Temporal Table

- This is new feature of SQL Server 2016.
- It is also called server versioned history table for particular table so there is a physical existence of this Temporal table.
- You can query against it and also its purpose is to keep history of particular record.

Comment: It's not clear if this is what the OP meant by "magic table". I don't see how anyone could even come by a *passing* acquaintance with these two features and think "they're so similar, I need someone to tell me what the important differences between them are".

Comment: Magic table in SQL Server are inserted and deleted that hold record that is inserted and updated or deleted. Will be helpful mainly in trigger.

Comment: The term "magic table" simply doesn't exists in the official SQL Server documentation, .NET people seem to use it: http://www.midnightdba.com/Jen/2011/03/maaaaaagic-tables/

Comment: I know very well what `inserted` and `deleted` are - I have answered *more than a few* questions on here about SQL Server. What I'm saying is I can't see someone looking at *those* (and applying the phrase "magic table", which is by no means universally understood to be a description of them), and on the other hand looking at temporal tables and *thinking that they look like similar features*

Comment: Yes. I agree . For me too both are completely different thing and still I try to figure out thing that explain OP to make understand what each thing are.